Error while writing Google map key secrets to Build.config through Android CI/CD GitHub pipeline actions
I’m setting up a CI/CD pipeline for an Android project in GitHub. The app uses Google Maps API keys for three different environments. Currently, I store these keys in the local.properties file and access them in the app/build.gradle to inject them into the BuildConfig.
As part of the CI/CD process, I've moved the Google Maps API keys into GitHub's repository secrets as environment variables. In the GitHub Actions workflow (build.yml), I’m setting these secrets as system environment variables to make them accessible during the build process, like this:
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        - name: set up JDK 11
          uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          java-version: '22'
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: gradle

        - name: Access DEV_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY
        env:
          DEV_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.DEV_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY }}
          run: echo 'DEV_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY=${{ secrets.DEV_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY }}' >> $GITHUB_ENV

        - name: Access STAGE_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY
        env:
           STAGE_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.STAGE_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY }}
        run: echo 'STAGE_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY=${{ secrets.STAGE_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY }}' >> $GITHUB_ENV

        - name: Access PROD_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY
        env:
           PROD_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.PROD_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY }}
        run: echo 'PROD_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY=${{ secrets.PROD_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY }}' >> $GITHUB_ENV

        - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
          run: chmod +x ./gradlew
        - name: Build with Gradle
          run: ./gradlew buildwhiskeyDebug

Writing these values into Build.config in app/build.gradle file as follows:
buildTypes {
   debug {
       def devApiKey = System.getenv("DEV_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY")
       buildConfigField "String", "DEV_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY", "\"${devApiKey}\""
   }
   release {
       def devApiKey = System.getenv("DEV_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY")
       buildConfigField "String", "DEV_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY", "\"${devApiKey}\""
   }
}

But getting CI/CD build process is failing with error:
'../android/web/BuildConfig.java:13: error: ';' expected
  public static final String DEV_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY = "***"; '
                                                                                     
'../android/web/BuildConfig.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
  public static final String DEV_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY = "***"; '

What am I missing here?

Please include the relevant snippet from BuildConfig.java:13 in your question.

Build process is failing, therefore I do not see Build.config file at all.

Build process works fine in Android Studio.
